# Gradle - Determine which dependency a jar is from

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I've recently run into a situation where I have a conflict because my Gradle dependency resolve results in 2 different-name jar files that are actually having the same contents. It's taken me a while to determine which dependency declaration a jar is from so I can exclude one of them. Is there an easy way that can allow gradle to generate some kind of report so that I can see which jars a dependency is resolved to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following task which will list out all the files brought in by each of your dependencies.

```
task dependencyFiles << {  
    configurations.compile.dependencies.all {  
        println "${it}: "  
        println configurations.compile.files(it).collect { it.name }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. The [project report plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/project_reports_plugin.html) is what you're looking for, especially the `dependencyReport` and `htmlDependencyReport` tasks it adds to the project, as well as the `dependencyInsight` command it allows to execute to get information about a specific dependency.